# Why doesn't my bounty appear anymore?

Tags: support, bounties

I opened a bounty on [Twitter (Social networking) Dataset](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340810/twitter-social-networking-dataset) less than 7 days ago.  Though the question has had an answer for a number of days now I was waiting to award the bounty until the last moment.  I just got an email and a banner alert indicating it was less than 24 hours to go, so I thought I'd go award it.

When I went to the question I had no such option, what happened to my bounty? (I should still have time left to award it)

To be clear: the banner showed up just before I posted this question, and I visited SO less than 24 hours ago.  If the question has already expired, then the banner must've been correct within the last 24 hours (and before), so it didn't show up when it should've yesterday.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bounty expired and was auto-awarded to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340810/twitter-social-networking-dataset/3389205#3389205).

Even though the banner said "less than 24 hours to go," it's not smart enough to tell you that "it's expiring right now!" -- maybe you could start a feature-request to get the banner to show the actual time remaining.

Comment: Fair enough, the alerts must've shown up late -- I visited the site yesterday less than 24 hours ago and didn't receive the banner, so there's no way the banner could've ever arrived correctly.

Comment: @Mark: That's entirely possible. Both e-mail notifications and banners tend to be a bit sluggish (same thing with badges).

Answer (score 0):

Possible:  That 24-hour message is cached, so when you received it, time was already up.

Does the email give you a clue for when you placed the bounty (can't remember).